# Remove crypto-browserify from NextJS build

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I've been focusing on reducing the build size of my app to as small as possible and I've noticed that `crypto-browserify` has been taking a large chunk of space. I understand that next polyfills the node module if required but I would like to specify that crypto-browserify is removed or replaced using the default crypto module.

Here's my current node_module bundle analyzed [image]

I did come across [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40271) which is very closely related, though I don't want to disable all of the polyfills.

Comment: What is the output of `npm why crypto-browserify`?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I didn't end up finding a solution for this, it looks like it's either you have all polyfills or none at all at the moment. It would be great if we could pick and choose which ones we need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found that I was importing the package `jsonwebtoken` to a few places on the client to decode JWTs. Restricting this package to just  my server fixed it. This package isn't optimized for being on a browser so alternatives should be used for anything on the client.

Comment: Did removing that package remove it from the NextJS bundle too?

Comment: Yup @JamieHunt saved me like 200kb